# Filesize calculation in command line

Tags: bash, expression

I'm trying to write a one line bash command that will show me filesize1 divided by filesize2.

What I have so far is

```
expr `du wednesday | cut -f1` / `du tuesday | cut -f1`
```

But it's showing `0`

These work, however

```
$ expr `du wednesday | cut -f1` / 1
13066388
$ expr `du wednesday | cut -f1` / 2
6533194
```

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`expr(1)` only does integer division.  From the [man page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/expr/):

```
 expr1 {*, /, %} expr2
         Return the results of multiplication, integer division, or
         remainder of integer-valued arguments.
```

You'll need to use a different tool; [`bc(1)`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/bc/) could do it, for example:

```
bc <<< "scale=2; $(du wednesday | cut -f1) / $(du tuesday | cut -f1)"
```

Comment: He is dividing ints, the issue is that his result is not an int.

Comment: Yeah - sorry.  Reworded.

Comment: +1 for adding the bc scale parameter.  Perhaps should be more explicit that `scale=2` presents the result to 2 decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

`expr $(du -b wednesday | cut -f1) / $(du -b tuesday | cut -f1)`
Back-ticks don't work with this command for some reason.
Because this works. one file is 7 bytes the other is 1295 bytes and the output is 185 bytes

Comment: i had to post another answer because i cant post comments if i haven't started the question

Comment: with out `-b` it would output blocks of 1 kb but the min value was 4